# How to tell bundler where the Gemfile is?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm trying to run a Ruby script from cron.

The script uses Bundler to manage gem dependencies. Since cron does not run in `$PWD` I get a 'Could not locate Gemfile' error from Bundler everytime, which makes sense since Gemfile is not in the currrent path when running from cron.

Is there a way to tell Bundler to use a Gemfile not in the current path?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to `cd` into the directory in question in your cron. You could also use the `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` environment variable to point at the Gemfile. Please [let us know](http://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues) if you have any problems with `BUNDLE_GEMFILE`.

Comment: Yehuda, thanks I was looking for a env variable to set before  calling 'bundle', but I ended up doing "cd /path && bundle exec foo.rb" it is porbably much easier that way.

Answer (score 2):

You could have the main script change its dir:

```
Dir.chdir File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

You might have to tweak it using `File.expand_path` to get your app's root dir (where the `Gemfile` is). Suppose your script is `/apps/myapp/bin/main.rb`; the `chdir` line would be:

```
Dir.chdir File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
```

Of course, you have to make sure your app doesn't break because of the chdir - but it shouldn't if you're `cd`-ing in the cron.

If the script is a daemon and you want it to be changed to the root dir `/` during normal operation, you can do that after calling `Bundler.setup` or `Bundler.require`.

While you could do `cd` in the cron, I prefer not to, because crons are already hard enough to read and maintain.